# Lambda Calculus beta reduction

Tags: lambda, lambda-calculus

I have the following lambda calculus:

```
( x ( λyz.xz ) ( λxy.zyx )) (( λyx.xyz ) ( λy.xz ))
```

which I already reduced:

```
alpha => ( x ( λyz.xz ) ( λxy.zyx )) (( λyx1.x1yz )) ( λy.xz ))
beta  => ( x ( λyz.xz ) ( λxy.zyx )) ( λx1.x1 ( λy.xz ) z )
```

My question: Why are the following reductions wrong? They seem to simplify the expression to me:

```
beta1 => ( x ( λyz.xz ) ( λxy.zyx )) ( λx1.x1 ( xz ))
beta2 => ( x ( λy.x ( λxy.zyx ))) ( λx1.x1 ( xz ))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid confusion I would suggest to alpha-rename a bit more.
So it would appear you have `x` and `z` in "scope" (they are not bound by any `λ` in your term), it is a good idea to make sure if you are referring to them or not.

I would rewrite your term like this:

```
(x (λy1,z1. x z1) (λx2,y2. z y2 x2)) ((λy3,x3. x3 y3 z) (λy4. x z))
```

I went quite far in renaming (this is unnecessary of course, but like this, we are sure which is which).

This term beta-reduces to

```
(x (λy1,z1. x z1) (λx2,y2. z y2 x2)) ((λx3. x3 (λy4. x z) z))
```

And then

```
(x (λy1,z1. x z1) (λx2,y2. z y2 x2)) ((λx3. x3 (λy4. x z) z))
```

This is indeed alpha-equivalent to what you wrote.
What you want to do then is apply `(λy4. x z)` to `z`.
This is not how you should be reading `x3 (λy4. x z) z` which could be also written with more parentheses like this `(x3 (λy4. x z)) z`.
Somehow this term is stuck because its head is a variable.

There isn't much you can do about it because this term is also involved in an application you can't reduce.
Perhaps you could also rewrite `(λy1,z1. x z1)` into `(λy1. x)` by eta-reduction.

So you cannot get `(x (λyz.xz) (λxy.zyx)) (λx1.x1 (x z))` and for the same reason, you can't beta-reduce it to `(x (λy.x (λxy.zyx))) (λx1.x1 (x z))` because you got the parenthesizing wrong.

`f x y` is read from left to right, you take `f` and you apply it to `x`, then you apply the result to `y`.

Answer (score 0):

I would keep this answer very simple.

To reduce to beta1 or beta2, notice that you have reduce ( λy.xz ) z in 
 "x1 ( λy.xz ) z" like "x1 **(** ( λy.xz ) z **)** ", so you can reduce., i.e, parenthesize/group last two expressions  ( λy.xz ) and z together, which is wrong.

This is not how it should work. While reducing lambda expressions you should maintain **left associativity**., 
i.e., always group leftmost expressions together like " **(** x1 ( λy.xz ) **)** z" instead of "x1 **(** ( λy.xz ) z **)**" [which is wrong].

With left associativity,if there are expressions like E1 E2 E3 E4,

you should group it like  ( ( (E1 E2) E3 ) E4 )

Thus, for the beta2, you can not reduce x1 ( λy.xz ) z to "x1 ( xz )". Same logic goes for beta1.

I hope that makes sense to you.